# Calculate $1+(1+2)+(1+2+3)+\cdots+(1+2+3+\cdots+n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I calculate $1+(1+2)+(1+2+3)+\cdots+(1+2+3+\cdots+n)$? I know that $1+2+\cdots+n=\dfrac{n+1}{2}\dot\ n$. But what should I do next?

Comment: See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle#Diagonals.

Comment: A [geometric proof](http://ckrao.wordpress.com/2012/03/14/the-sum-of-consecutive-squares-formula/) of sum of squares.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint:** use also that
$$
1^2 + 2^2 + \dots + n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6
$$

$$
1 + (1+2) + \dots + (1 +2+\dots +n) =
\frac{1(1+1)}2 + \frac{2(2+1)}2 + \dots + \frac{n(n+1)}2 
\\=\frac 12 \left[
(1^2 + 1) + (2^2 + 2 ) + \dots + (n^2 + n)
\right]
\\=\frac 12 \left[
(1^2 + 2^2 + \dots + n^2) + (1 + 2 + \dots + n)
\right]
$$

Answer (score 12):

[image: Pascal Triangle]

Sorry for the horrible resolution. In any case: That's Pascal's triangle. The blue is the triangular numbers. The red is the sum of the blue (can you see why?)

Now you can use the formula for the elements of Pascal's triangle: The $n$th row and $r$th column is $\dbinom nr$. (You start counting the rows and columns from 0. The rows can be counted from the left *or* the right, doesn't matter.)

The answer is $\dbinom{n+2}3=\dfrac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3!}$.

Comment: Can you see why the blue are the triangular numbers, by the way?

Comment: +1 for not just offering the combinatorial answer (which is _much_ cleaner than going through any sum-of-squares formula) but doing a great job of explaining *why* it's true.  This is IMHO the best answer by far here.

Comment: brilliant!${{{}}}$

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n(1+\ldots+k)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k(k+1)}2=\frac12\left(\sum_{k=1}^nk^2+\sum_{k=1}^nk\right)$$

and now

$$\sum_{k=1}^nk^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}
&1+(1+2)+(1+2+3)+\cdots+(1+2+3+\cdots+n)\\
&=n\cdot 1+(n-2)\cdot 2+(n-3)\cdot 3+\cdots +1\cdot n\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^n(n+1-r)r\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^n {n+1-r\choose 1}{r\choose 1}\\
&={n+2\choose 1+2}\\
&={n+2\choose 3}\\
&=\frac16 n(n+1)(n+2)
\end{align}$$

Comment: This seems to be wrong as the last expression is the sum of the first $\;n\;$ squared natural numbers, which is *not* what we have.

Comment: Not really... the sum of the first $n$ squared natural numbers is $\frac16 n(n+1)(2n+1)$

Comment: Oh, I see now the second parentheses more carefully. Thanks. +1

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** :

It is the summation of $\sum \frac {n(n+1)}2$ from 1 to n

which is equal to $\sum (\frac {n^2}2 + \frac n2)$ from 1 to n

Answer (score 1):

I thought about this problem differently than others so far. The problem is asking you to essentially sum up a bunch of sums. So by observation, it appears that $1$ appears $n$ times, $2$ appears $n-1$ times, $3, n-2$ times and so on, with only $1$ $n$ term. So instead, let's add up a sum from $1$ to $n$ which does this. It should be of the form $\sum_{i=1}^{n} n(n+1)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}n^2+n.$ Since sums are linear, decompose this into two sums, and apply the formulas you know for the sum of the squares and the sum of the integers.

Answer (score 1):

Sums we know:
$\sum^n_{i=1} i = 1+2+\cdots+n=\frac{n^2+n}{2}$
$\sum^n_{i=1} i^2 = 1^2 + 2^2 + \dots + n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$

Your sum is $$(1+2+3+ \cdots + n) + (1 + 2 + \cdots + (n-1)) + (1 + 2 + \cdots + (n-2)) + \cdots + (1)$$ $$= \sum^n_{k=1} \sum^k_{i=1} i$$ $$= \sum^n_{k=1} \frac{k^2+k}{2} = \frac 12 (\sum^n_{k=1} k^2 + \sum^n_{k=1} k)$$

NOTE: You can reorder the terms if the are a finite number of them.  So if you're going to be taking a limit as $n \to \infty$ don't do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

The n-th partial sum of the triangular numbers as listed in http://oeis.org/A000292 .